# Self Sizing CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uicollectionview

I try to make my collectionView Cell height as per content.
I tried with Self Sizing CollectionViewCell but it is not working.
I used auto layout in CollectionView Cell.

**Cell have three Labels with `top,left,bottom,right Constraints` & have Vertical Compression Ration is Required(1000).**

My code is as follow:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let flowlayout = col.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
   flowlayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake((self.view.frame.size.width - 60) / 2 , 1)
    }
}


//MARK: CollectionView

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 17
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = col.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.lbl1.text = "Lorem ispum Simple text to show if it working or not"
    }
    else{
        cell.lbl1.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    }       
    return cell
}
```

**Some People are saying that it is not possible for collectionView Self Sizing Cell, even though Apple claims it.
You have to calculate manually.**

**If I try to calculate it manually then I am also unable to get cell object in `sizeForItemIndexPath`**

Comment: "it is not working". What happens? Is the size too small, too large, does it not show at all, does it not change properly, does the iPhone explode when you try?

Comment: @fishinear  It shows height as per estimated height only. does not take height as per Auto Layout